# Pyplot yaxis organization and standardization with multiple data sets in one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

While working through Python Crash Course, I came to this problem while trying to plot two sets of data from two different .csv files.  The files contain dates and temperature information for two cities.  The dates are the same and lay out just fine on the xaxis, but the yaxis is cluttered, out of order, and unreadable.  Here is my code so far:

```
#Python 3.7

import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as pyp 
from datetime import datetime

filename_1= "sitka_weather_2014.csv"
with open(filename_1) as f1:
    reader= csv.reader(f1)
    header_row= next(reader)

    for index, column_header in enumerate(header_row):
        print(index, column_header)

    highs_SKA, dates_SKA= [], []
    for row in reader:
        high_SKA= float(int(row[1]))
        highs_SKA.append(high_SKA)

        date= datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
        dates_SKA.append(date)

filename_2= "death_valley_2014.csv"
with open(filename_2) as f2:
    reader2= csv.reader(f2)
    header_row2= next(reader2)

    for index2, column_header2 in enumerate(header_row2):
        print(index2, column_header2)

    highs_dv= []
    dates_dv= []
    for row in reader2:
        high_dv= row[1]
        highs_dv.append(high_dv)

        date_dv= datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
        dates_dv.append(date_dv)

pyp.figure(dpi=100, figsize=(7, 5))
pyp.plot(dates_SKA, highs_SKA, c='red', alpha=0.5)
pyp.plot(dates_dv, highs_dv, c='green', alpha=0.5)
pyp.show()
```

I have tried to define custom axis labels and scale, but cannot figure out how to do so for just yaxis only.  I read that a problem may be due to trying to plot strings, but I am unable to convert the second .csv file's temperatures to integers.  I get a "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10" when trying to convert "death_valley.csv" temperatures.  It seems to work fine for the "sitka_weather_2014.csv".

I want to standardize the yaxis. My main question for now is how can I get the yaxis to cooperate with both of the data.

EDIT: 
[What the plot looks like at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC12H.jpg)

EDIT_2: 
In an attempt to convert the highs_dv list (from the second file) to integers, I tried:

```
high_dv= [None if high_dv is ' ' else float(high_dv) for high_dv in row[1]]
highs_dv.append(high_dv)
```

This gave me a "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"

I also tried to use a for loop in case I was mistaken about the list comprehension for high_dv:

```
for high_dv in row[1]:
    if high_dv is ' ':
        high_dv = None
    else:
        high_dv= float(high_dv)
    highs_dv.append(high_dv)
```

Also tried:

```
for high_dv in row[1]:
    if high_dv.isnumeric():
        high_dv= float(high_dv)
    else:
        high_dv= None
    highs_dv.append(high_dv)
```

Both of the above loops gave me "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (360,) and (797,)".

EDIT_3:
I realized that my looping was incorrect in my second edit.  I created a second loop where I shouldn't have, for example:

```
for row in reader:
    for high_dv in row[1]:
```

After playing with it for a while, I was able to convert to float with:

```
for row in reader:
    if row[1] is ' ':
        high_dv= None
    else:
        high_dv= float(row[1])
    highs_dv.append(high_dv)
```

Comment: This is one case where uploading pictures would be a good idea. Show an example plot and explain what you think is wrong with it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Are you really sure? I see that the y-axis looks similar to the error of your proposed duplicate, but I cannot understand why an introduction of categorical x-axes would affect this problem here, where they convert the x data form string to datetime. I think there are several things to optimize here, but setting up x-data seems to me not to be the problem here.

Comment: The question is about the y-axis, right? This would be solved by converting the data to numbers, as e.g. shown in the duplicate. The problem here is that this approach seems to fail for some cases. But there is no [mcve] shown that would allow to judge on the reason - most probably the csv file contains some invalid characters or similar. Once there is a [mcve] provided feel free to notify me again to reopen it.

Comment: I agree, as always an mcv example is necessary. That means at least additionally the first three lines (as text) of your two data files and the code, where you tried to define custom scales. Until then, I can only tell you about problems I see already in your post: the value error message you describe is thrown e.g. if you try to convert a string containing a float to int. (e.g. `int('3.4')`). As I'd expect your temperature data to be probably of type float, imo you should use only that cast: `high_SKA = float(row[1])` and `high_dv = float(row[1])`

Comment: @C.Matt Did you already try some suggestions or consider posting the structure of your datafiles?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I took a look at the duplicate question and tried to work it out based on the information there.  I also posted some of the text of the .csv for the two.  I hope it is enough to meet MCV.

Comment: Well I guess this is now concrete enough not to be a duplicate anymore, so I'll reopen. However, I don't think I can help more here, since the initial code was working fine with one file, but not the other, suggesting the problem is in the files, which we still don't have access to. In the edit, the problem is about array shapes, yet both shown arrays are of the same size. So it's still not a complete and verifiable example. But maybe someone else has the time to play the guessing game here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I believe you were correct with the duplicate.  It was my ignorance that threw it all off. 
 Thank you for your help and patience.